# TypeError ..... got multiple values for argument when trying to load_mnist(...) function

Tags: python, function, typeerror

Please assist with the error shown below

```
def load_mnist(path, kind='train'):
    """Load MNIST data from `path`"""
    labels_path = os.path.join(path, 
                               '%s-labels-idx1-ubyte' % kind)
    images_path = os.path.join(path, 
                               '%s-images-idx3-ubyte' % kind)

    with open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:
        magic, n = struct.unpack('>II', 
                                 lbpath.read(8))
        labels = np.fromfile(lbpath, 
                             dtype=np.uint8)

    with open(images_path, 'rb') as imgpath:
        magic, num, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII", 
                                               imgpath.read(16))
        images = np.fromfile(imgpath, 
                             dtype=np.uint8).reshape(len(labels), 784)
        images = ((images / 255.) - .5) * 2

    return images, labels
```

Then:

```
X_train, y_train = load_mnist('.\\Chapter 12\\MNIST', 'labels-idx1-ubyte', kind='train')
```

Error message is:

> TypeError: load_mnist() got multiple values for argument 'kind'

Directory content is:

```
t10k-images.idx3-ubyte

t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte

train-images.idx3-ubyte

train-labels.idx1-ubyte
```

Comment: Your `load_mnist` takes two arguments, but you are passing three to it. What do you expect that to do? From what I can gather, you don't want to pass `'labels-idx1-ubyte'` to the function...

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `load_mnist` takes two arguments but you did give three arguments to `load_mnist` (like @uneven_mark said)

Let me correct your code

```
X_train, Y_train = load_mnist('.\\Chapter 12\\MNIST', kind='train')
```

There is no error in `load_mnist` function, the error is in the variable assigment

Comment: I have a new problem when I use the recommended code, '''
  File "<ipython-input-11-b8c8b7a7912e>", line 1, in <module>
    X_train, y_train = load_mnist('.\\Chapter 12\\MNIST',  kind='train')

  File "<ipython-input-2-8bfea6c39b39>", line 12, in load_mnist
    with open(labels_path, 'rb') as lbpath:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\Chapter 12\\MNIST\\train-labels-idx1-ubyte' '''

Comment: ask a new question